# prolog why eclipse clp cannot compile this programme - syntax error

Tags: prolog

OK here is the code

```
http://pastebin.com/dEKMKvp9
```

Could you tell me why i cant compile it?

It says always:
syntax error: postfix/infix operator expected

Thank you for your time!

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflwo.com/help/mcve), please.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't compile because of the first block:

```
predicates
nondeterm pierwiastek(Real, Integer,Real, Integer, Real,Real) %pierwiastek(X, n, D, K, Y,R)
nondeterm pierwiastek2(Real, Integer,Real)
kontynuuj(Char)
%nondeterm potega(Real, Integer)
nondeterm potega(Real, Integer, Real)
nondeterm powtorz
nondeterm program.

goal
program.

clauses
```

This is not valid code in Eclipse CLP..

Answer (score 0):

You code was apparently written for VisualProlog (or its preceding version, TurboProlog). VisualProlog is a logic programming language but not a Prolog language, despite its name, as defined by current official and de facto Prolog standards.

The first step to convert the code to run under the ECLiPSe Prolog system is to delete the `predicates`, `goal`, and `clauses` headers.